# Won't boot, blinking cursor after power-outage

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot

I dual-booted my Mac with Ubuntu and it was running fine, I wen't out the office but continued to use it via VNC just to set up my environment, this obviously caused a lot of updates that wanted me to restart my computer (Something I couldn't do as it would boot straight into mac unless someone selected Linux on ReFit). Then there was a power outage causing it to be shut-off one day, I came back into the office today to find that it refuses to boot, I just get a black screen with a flashing white cursor, it does boot into the Mac no problem, any solutions?

**edit mac partition Inspector:**

*** Report for internal hard disk ***

Current GPT partition table:
 #      Start LBA      End LBA  Type
 1             40       409639  EFI System (FAT)
 2         409640    212872855  Mac OS X HFS+
 3      212873216   1894903807  Basic Data
 4     1894903808   1953262983  Linux Swap

Current MBR partition table:
 # A    Start LBA      End LBA  Type
 1              1       409639  ee  EFI Protective
 2         409640    212872855  af  Mac OS X HFS+
 3 *    212873216   1894903807  83  Linux
 4     1894903808   1953262983  82  Linux swap / Solaris

MBR contents:
 Boot Code: GRUB

Partition at LBA 40:
 Boot Code: None (Non-system disk message)
 File System: FAT32
 Listed in GPT as partition 1, type EFI System (FAT)

Partition at LBA 409640:
 Boot Code: GRUB
 File System: HFS Extended (HFS+)
 Listed in GPT as partition 2, type Mac OS X HFS+
 Listed in MBR as partition 2, type af  Mac OS X HFS+

Partition at LBA 212873216:
 Boot Code: GRUB
 File System: ext4
 Listed in GPT as partition 3, type Basic Data
 Listed in MBR as partition 3, type 83  Linux, active

Partition at LBA 1894903808:
 Boot Code: None
 File System: Unknown
 Listed in GPT as partition 4, type Linux Swap
 Listed in MBR as partition 4, type 82  Linux swap / Solaris

**Edit Edit:**

It seems to not even get into the Grub loader, as pressing Shift does nothing, I select Linux from rEFit then it goes straight to a black screen with a flashing text input cursor, I can do nothing, only restart and do it all again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I recommend you to be sure, that your linux partition works fine. I think, you can check  it under your MacOS. If no - get the Ubuntu LiveCD\USB and try access root partition, boot folder (/boot partitaion, if divided). If all seems to be working right you have to check your bootloader settings.

You also can try boot manually to your system from Live distributive with GRUB. You have to  enter GRUB console mode, select your root device, kernel file and process booting

Comment: @MattC Please *edit your question* to include that information there, rather than a comment.

Comment: Once I get into the options in the LiveCD, how would I manually boot the GRUB?

I am able to launch Ubuntu from the CD.